# What's the logic behind using 'a' - 'A' instead of "32" or the space character?

Tags: c, type-conversion, ascii

This is a code from the book "*The C Programming Language*" which maps a single character to lower case for the ASCII character set and returns unchanged, if the character is not an upper case letter:

```
int lower(int c)
{
    if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
        return c + 'a' - 'A';
    else
        return c;
}
```

I don't understand the logic behind `return c + 'a' - 'A';`.

Why didn't they simply put `' '` or the number `32` instead of `'a' - 'A'`?

Comment: The (original? misguided) intent is to avoid dependence on ASCII codes... but the rest of the code relies on it, so it's kinda bizarre. `32` would have been fine (with possibly a comment `/* works in ASCII */`)

Comment: @pmg - It relies on the code points being contiguous, not on them being ASCII per-se.

Comment: That's what I meant, @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, thanks :-)

Comment: "_Why didn't they simply put `' `' or the number `32` instead of `'a' - 'A'`?_" - Because the intent is clearer and will work even on non-ASCII systems as long as the code points are contigous _and_ even if `'a'` happens to be less than `'A'`.

Comment: EBCDIC is not contigous but some other exotic encoding might be.

Comment: Pre-ANSI C, you needed to write your own functions like this. But Standard C has `tolower` and `isupper`, which avoids these issues.

Comment: @TedLyngmo It also relies on the ordering of upper- vs lower-case characters.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Indeed. Some exotic system may have them ordered differently. That'd be fun :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the ASCII character set `'a' - 'A'` just happens to have a value of 32. It's completely unrelated to the ASCII space character `' '` also having a value of 32, so it makes no sense to replace `'a' - 'A'` with `' '`.

Using `'a' - 'A'` is much more meaningful and understandable than `32`, and also doesn't tie the implementation to using a specific character set (though `a-z` and `A-Z` need to be contiguous for it to work, which isn't true for all character sets).

Comment: To be clear, the letters do not need to be contiguous for `c + 'a' - 'A'` to convert uppercase to lowercase. This works in EBCDIC too, even though the letters are not contiguous there. It only requires a uniform distance between corresponding characters. The letters need to be contiguous for `c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'` to correctly detect uppercase letters.

Answer (score 2):

Why not 32?  Because "magic numbers" are bad.

By using `'a'-'A'` it makes it clear to the reader that the difference in character encoding between upper case and lower case is being added to the current character encoding.

Note that this also depends on the set of upper case characters being contiguous as well as the set of lower case characters.  This is true for ASCII but necessarily in general

Comment: You know, it doesn't depending on A-Z being contiguous, just that they're all in the same order, with (if any) the same gaps between them.  I suspect `'A'-'a'` would probably actually work for EBCDIC, even though the letters aren't all contiguous, and I think `'A'-'a'` is negative.

Answer (score 1):

**c - 'A':** gives you the letter number in the alphabet; not in the character set:

so for example if you pass 'A' to `c - 'A'` you get 0, because everything subtracted by itself becomes zero; if you pass 'B' you get 1; if you pass 'C' you get 2 and so on. You get a number between 0 to 25 (The English alphabet includes 26 letters which we count from 1)

**c - 'a':** makes your upper-case letter a lower-case letter. It puts your letter number in the lower-case sequence in the character set.

so for example if you pass 'A', you get 0; then *0 + 'a'* gives you the letter 'a'. if you pass 'B', you get 1; then *1 + 'a'* gives you 'b' which comes right after 'a'.  if you pass 'C', you get 2; then *2 + 'a'* gives you 'c' which is two letters after 'a' and so on.

**Also consider the following:**

- Take a look at ASCII table.
- This function is designed generally to work with the character sets that their order corresponds to the English alphabet order. Character sets that their characters are contiguous like: A, B, C, D... and their lower-case and upper-case letters are a fixed distance.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same reason as for writing things like

```
val = 10 * val + digitchar - '0';
```

when you're writing code to convert a string of digits to the corresponding integer.

The "obvious" way to write it would be

```
val = 10 * val + digitchar - 48;
```

But where did that magic number 48 come from?  You had to look it up on the ASCII chart, and if I'm not familiar with it, I have to look it up on an ASCII chart to figure out how your program works.  It saves both of us time if you write the constant '0' instead.  (And, incidentally, using the constant '0' means that the program is portable to a machine using a character set other than ASCII, if anyone cares.)

Similarly, if I know that the codes for the upper- and the lower-case letters are in the same order but separated by some amount, using the computation `'A' - 'a'` to represent that amount is again easier on both me and my reader than it would be if I went to my ASCII chart and worked out that the offset is actually 32.

In both cases, the principle here is *Let the machine do the dirty work*.

I agree, it's a little cryptic at first.  If you're used to looking things up on the ASCII chart whenever you need to, it can be very disorienting to see those strange scraps of code like `'A' - 'a'` and `digitchar - '0'`.  Once you get used to the idioms, though, they're *so* much easier and less trouble.

Comment: `val = 10 * val + digitchar - '0';` also has the advantage of being portable, strictly-conforming C code when `digitchar` actually is a digit character.

Comment: @AndrewHenle You mean, the C Standard actually does say that, whatever the character set is, the 10 digits are guaranteed to be contiguous and ascending?  Right.

Comment: [Exactly](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.1p3): "In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous."

Comment: For those following along at home, what Andrew's saying is that while `'A'-'a'` in the original question is preferable to using `32`, it is still not perfect and not guaranteed to work, because it is theoretically possible for there to be a machine out there, with a conforming C compiler, but with a braindamaged  character set where `B` and `b` have a different offset between them than do `A` and `a`.  The fragment `digitchar - '0'`, on the other hand, that *is* guaranteed to work (as long as 0 ≤ `digitchar` < 10).

Answer (score 0):

Think about the authors perspective, they might tired to build up the knowlege on earlier pages and introduced to ASCII codes. They also discussed about type conversion in ealier code example and paragraph. For beginners the author tried to make them understand and use int and char interchangebly. As others discussed it is cleaner. Someone already know about C programming this question might arise.

We can avoid magic numbers in this case `32` as well.